# I have matching numbers of aesthetics and options in an R program but I keep getting the same error that they are not the same length

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run the following code, I get an error stating: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

```
library(ggtree)
library(ape)

# Read in the tree files
coii <- read.tree("Final Project/Dryad_CoII_tree.ntree")
fibro <- read.tree("Final Project/NEWDryad_TG3_Fibrobacteres.tree")
trepo <- read.tree("Final Project/NEWDryad_Treponema_I.tree")

# Define the labels and colors for each species and genus
species_labels <- c("Microcerotermes sp.", "Microcerotermes parvus",
                    "Nasutitermitinae Unclassified", "Atlantitermes sp.",
                    "Trinervitermes sp.", "Cornitermes sp.", "Nasutitermes takasagoensis")
species_colors <- c("#e41a1c", "#377eb8", "#4daf4a", "#984ea3", "#ff7f00", "#ffff33", "#a65628")
genus_labels <- c("Microcerotermes", "Nasutitermitinae", "Atlantitermes", "Trinervitermes", "Cornitermes")
genus_colors <- c("#e41a1c", "#4daf4a", "#984ea3", "#ff7f00", "#ffff33")

# Define the size of the circles for each tip based on relative abundance
# In this example, I'm using the relative abundance values from the sample labels
fibrolabs <- gsub("[^:]*:", "", attr(fibro$tip.label, "Labels"))
sizes <- unname(as.numeric(sub(".*RelAb=(.*)", "\\1", fibrolabs)))

# Assign the appropriate color to each tip based on species or genus
colors <- rep("black", length(fibrolabs))
for (i in seq_along(species_labels)) {
  colors[grep(species_labels[i], fibrolabs)] <- species_colors[i]
}
for (i in seq_along(genus_labels)) {
  colors[grep(genus_labels[i], fibrolabs)] <- genus_colors[i]
}

# Create the ggtree object
ggtree_obj <- ggtree(fibro, ladderize = "right") +
  geom_tiplab(aes(color = colors), size = 2) +
  geom_tippoint(aes(size = sizes), color = "gray", shape = 21) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", species_colors, genus_colors)) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 10), trans = "sqrt")

# Plot the tree
ggtree_obj
```

How can I modify the code to avoid this error? I tried the rainbow function and that didn’t produce errors, but the colors are supposed to correspond to each genus

Comment: What is `length(unique(fibro$colors))`? Is it 1 + 7 + 5 = 13, the number of colors in your specification?